# How should I organize a list of items by their category in Django?

Tags: python, django, templates, loops

I have a "Category" model, and a "Project" model, which contains a ForeignKey to "Category." So each Project can only belong to one Category.

I want to create a list that ends up looking like the following:

**Category 1**
Project 1
Project 2

**Category 2**
Project 3
Project 4

etc.

I think the following psuedocode will work:

```
<ul class="category-list">
{% for c in category %}
    <li>{{ c.title }}</li>
    <ul class="project-list">
        {% for p in project WHERE CATEGORY = C %}
            <li>{{ p.title }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The part I'm having trouble with is the "WHERE CATEGORY = C" part. How do I express this in Django template code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the regroup tag http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#regroup

Answer (score 3):

```
{% for p in c.project_set.all %}
```

Look in the Django documentation for [following relationships backwards](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects).